# Overwriting a vector

Tags: c++, c

I have a 2d vector that contains these elements:

```
1 3
4 6
```

I use a function to overwrite the vector by adding 1 to each element:

```
overwrite(){

for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<columns; j++){
       2d_vector[i][j] + 1;
   }
}
```

My task requires me to use another function to print the matrix onto console where i use this function:

```
print_on_console(){
 for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<columns; j++){
      cout <<  2d_vector[i][j] << " ";
}
cout << "\n";
}
}
```

My expected output should be:

```
2 4
5 7
```

however it prints the old vector and the overwritten vector is not stored in memory and the output is:

```
1 3
4 6
```

Comment: Please provide [mre]. Currently, it's unclear how you invoke those functions.

Comment: `_matrix[i][j] + 1;` has no effect. A decent compiler should warn about this. Turn on warnings and pay attention to them. Voting to close as typo

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius glad to see that this not only happens to me. Sometimes a non-complete example is already more than sufficient ;)

Comment: nevertheless you should have included a [mcve], please next time...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Oh, I see. Thank you :) I thought that this was, somehow, related to pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference issues, that I am used to seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```cpp
_matrix[i][j] + 1;
```

takes each element, adds one, then discards the result.

Instead, you should use one of the following (all equivalent, in this case):

```cpp
_matrix[i][j] = _matrix[i][j] + 1;
_matrix[i][j] += 1;
_matrix[i][j]++;
++_matrix[i][j];
```